# Find the derivative of $ \frac{E^2*RL}{(Rs+RL)^2} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

So I have to find the partial derivative $\frac{d}{dRL}$ which means that all variables except RL are constants. In the end I get $\frac {E^2((Rs+RL)^2-2RL)}{(Rs+RL)^3}$ and the answer should be $\frac {E^2*(Rs-RL)}{(Rs+RL)^3}$

I arrived at that answer by using $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ -> $\frac {g*f' - f*g'}{g^2}$

Could someone please help me because I've been stuck on this for an hour

Comment: As the first step, you should get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial RL}\left(\frac{E^2 RL}{(Rs+RL)^2}\right) = \frac{E^2 (Rs + RL)^2 - E^2 RL(2(Rs + RL))}{(Rs + RL)^4}.$$Did you get this?

Comment: Yeah, exactly the same

Comment: If so, you can factorise the $E^2$ from the numerator. The remaining part should become $(Rs)^2 - (RL)^2$. Did you get that?

Comment: @ythhtrg if Rs and RL are actually single variables, you should probably right them as $R_s$ and $R_L$ instead.

Comment: How? When I factored out $E^2$ I got the answer I wrote in the main post

Comment: I also simplified one Rs+RL

Comment: If you factor $E^2$, the remaining part is $$(Rs+RL)^2 - RL(2(Rs + RL)) = (Rs+ RL)^2 - 2(RL)(Rs) - 2(RL)^2.$$Can you get the answer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial RL} (\dfrac{E^{2}RL}{(Rs+RL)^{2}})= \frac{\partial}{\partial RL} (E^{2}RL\cdot\dfrac{1}{(Rs+RL)^{2}})
\end{equation}

For convenience, I'm going to apply the product rule $(f\cdot g)'=f'\cdot g+f\cdot g'$
\begin{equation}
=\frac{\partial (E^{2}RL)}{\partial RL}\cdot(Rs+RL)^{-2}+E^{2}RL\cdot\frac{\partial ((Rs+RL)^{-2})}{\partial RL}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=E^{2}\cdot(Rs+RL)^{-2}-2E^{2}RL\cdot(Rs+RL)^{-3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\frac{E^{2}}{(Rs+RL)^{2}}-\frac{2E^{2}RL}{(Rs+RL)^{3}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\frac{E^{2}(Rs+RL)-2E^{2}RL}{(Rs+RL)^{3}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\frac{E^{2}Rs+E^{2}RL-2E^{2}RL}{(Rs+RL)^{3}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\frac{E^{2}Rs-E^{2}RL}{(Rs+RL)^{3}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\frac{E^{2}(Rs-RL)}{(Rs+RL)^{3}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Wow, thank you!